# Exported mesh with custom normal error using Hard Ops

Tags: mesh, add-on, normals, data-blocks

I'm using the Blender addon [HardOps (0.9.87.26)](https://blendermarket.com/products/hard-ops--boxcutter-ultimate-bundle). I can't remove the sharpen edges effect from the mesh and it seems to mess up the normals on import to another scene

- Ive tried removing custom norml data
- joining it to another mesh
- flipping normals

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Weirdly i found If I replaced the material it fixed the mesh? (It only had a diff texture)
So fixed -  but interested how it happened.

Comment: HardOps is a third-party addon, not part of Blender so any questions / comments about it should be addressed directly to the authors.

Comment: Apart from what @JohnEason correctly remarked, it is quite unlikely that the material itself created or removed sharp edges. But without the slightest idea what kind of material it was I can neither deny nor confirm it had an influence. And what is the top screenshot supposed to be? This looks like simple backface culling... Anyway, whatever HardOps is usually doing is just execute several Blender steps in one click for you, like beveling, shading smooth, creating hard edges. So if there is a problem removing those settings with HardOps, you can always do it manually with Blender's own tools.

Comment: the material did not add or remove the sharp edges - but somehow it affected the normals or the way it was displaying - by removing it and readding it the faces displayed correctly - it was just a standard diff texture, no normal maps or anything extra. (I can only say it seemed like a normals problem - from the way that it looks)